# Convert Date/Time format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, time

I have the following date/time format in many Excel sheets: 2021-11-23T23:49:34.000+0000

However, it is very bulky. It's ugly to use in graphs and you can't really do any date/time math with it. Is there a good wat to format this? Maybe something like 11/23/2021 23:49:34. I've tried different cell formulas as well as general number formatting.

Comment: See this, there are several methods given: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68842642/how-can-i-format-a-string-into-a-date-time-format/68843252

Comment: Actually, I see that is for ISO 8601 and this is in DT3 format.  Do you have to handle that timezone offset (the +0000) or are you ignoring it?

Comment: Ignoring the timezone offset. Just needed the general date and time separated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))
+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
```

The first part grabs the date, the second part grabs the time.  If you need the microseconds, use this:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))
+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,12))
```

If you need to handle the time offset (+0000) then you can add these parts:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))
+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,12))
+TIMEVALUE(CONCAT(MID(A1, 25, 2), ":", MID(A1, 27, 2)))
*IF(MID(A1, 24,1)="+", 1, -1)
```

where the third line formats the offset into a timevalue and the fourth line captures the sign.